# Python - regex issue with getting formula consisted between ><

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm practicing regular expressions on html file.
My goal is to fetch tittle of the file:

```
<tittle>Popular baby names</tittle>
```

I tried something like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'>.+<')
```

and instead of what I'm looking for I'm getting:

```
((1791, 1794), '>?<')
((2544, 2547), '>1<')
((2605, 2608), '>2<')
```

I've read that dot represents any character but a newline. That makes me wonder why it isn't working.

Comment: Rather than `+.` you want `.+`.

Comment: If you're a visual learner it's a good idea to practice your regex on sites like https://regex101.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch what's inside the tag only, use capturing groups `()`.

```py
import re

s = '<tittle>Popular baby names</tittle> some text <title>Other title</title> <strong>bold</strong>'

re.findall(r'>([\w\s]+)</', s)

# ['Popular baby names', 'Other title', 'bold']
```